# Visual studio for mac shows a small unwanted window

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

Recently i have been experiencing a weird issue with Visual studio for mac.
While doing any development a small window appears out of no where on Visual studio and stays there. And i can't do any code writing until i kill the Visual studio. Or may be i don't know the solution to this problem. I tried searching the internet but could not find any solution to this. I have attached a screenshot of the window below.
[image]

If any one has encountered  and resolved this issue please help. Because this has become irritating.

Comment: in the Help menu, "Report a Problem"

Comment: This is a known bug in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10. There is some bug in the drag and drop code. I sometimes see this when clicking other tags and accidentally starting a drag. There is no fix for this currently. Only thing you can do is restart Visual Studio for Mac 8.10. It is reported on the Microsoft Developer Community already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been fixed.

You can check this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-for-Mac-freezes/1461790.

This issue is fixed with the Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Preview 1 release.